# HttpURLConnection doesn't receive response

Tags: java

I've WebService invoke code in a loop in a Thread. I build URL with diffirent parameters and and invoke the WS using HttpURLConnection as follows:

```
public void run() {
    //establish connection to db in another class

    while(true) {
        //Get args value from another class

        for(String arg : args) {
            try {
                String invokeWS = "URL is built here with encoded args";

                URL obj = new URL(invokeWS);

                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
                con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
                int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                con.disconnect();

                System.out.println(response.toString());
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                System.out.println("Unsupported Encoding Exception");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                System.out.println("Malformed URL Exception");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("IO Exception");
            }
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted Exception");
        }
    }
}
```

But if the network connection drops out after the 'GET' is sent and before the response is received then control never returns to the Thread in the loop. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It sounds like maybe the connection is hanging.  Does anything appear in your logs?  Do you know what the response code is?  Have you tried accessing the URL directly?

Comment: Yes, I can access URL directly. Issue is that once network is restored I want the execution of code in the loop continue. But the excution control never returns to the thread.

Comment: You may set a timeout for your `HttpURLConnection`.  Then, should the call exceed that time, you would catch an exception.

Comment: Check con.getResponseCode() is 200 ok then read data from bufferedReader.

Comment: @SumeshTG and what if you need to also get the response from any other status ?

Comment: Yes, I get response code 200 when Network is restored. But issue is the control back to thread. I'm setting the following as suggeted:       setConnectTimeout(5000);
con.setReadTimeout(5000);

Comment: If the connection fails for some reason, you need to retry. You need a proper handling of the Exceptions and retry counts.

Comment: setReadTimeout(10000) might've done the trick for me. Looks like it is working with my initial testing

Answer (score 0):

Avoid Looping in runnable. I face the same issue i cut down my looping.I loaded straight away data and then looped at my end out side runnable task.

Comment: Are you suggesting take the while loop block out of run() and put it in another method and call that method from run(). Not sure how that will help. Unless I'm missing your point entirely. Can you please give an example

Comment: Yes, It returns the expected text with response code 200.